# str.split(' ').map() vs arr.map(), for fixed input

Tags: javascript

Curious if there is any benefit to choosing one of these approaches over the other. Here's an illustration.

```
'one two'.split(' ').map(string => doSomething(string));
```

vs

```
['one', 'two'].map(string => doSomething(string));
```

I've seen the first approach in a few popular front-end libraries, but the second one makes more sense to me when reading through code quickly. Is this just a style choice? Or is there some sort of obscure benefit to splitting a spaced out string versus just mapping through an array?

Comment: @user2864740 Really?

Comment: Do you want to have the extra processing step?

Comment: @user2864740, No it isn't. `'one two'.split(' ')` produces `['one', 'two']`

Comment: Are there any examples to this claim that library uses `"foo bar".split` instead of `["foo", "bar"]`?

Comment: @DanielCook Fair enough :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I've seen it in a few of the initialization scripts for instrumentation libraries that they have you paste into an HTML page.

Comment: If you have a large array of single-word strings that you're initializing with literals in the code, then I can see using `'foo bar baz'.split()` as a sort of poor man's version of Perl's `qw()` or Ruby's `%w()`, but it feels like optimizing for programmer keystrokes instead of readability.

Comment: Usually you use `.split()` because you already have the data in a string variable. I would never write it with a literal like that.

Comment: I've seen it in jQuery when creating several methods that serve a similar purpose. Pretty sure they just do it to save a few extra bytes.

Comment: Here's an example that creates `[object XYZ]` properties for type checking: `jQuery.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object Error".split(" "), function(i, name) {
 class2type[ "[object " + name + "]" ] = name.toLowerCase();
});`

Answer (score 0):

`['one', 'two']` is the result of `'one two'.split(' ')`, so no difference.

[`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> The `split()` method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the reason you would use one versus the other is dependent on the type of your variable; whether you already have a string or an array.

Comment: I'm aware they accomplish the same things, but was curious if there was some obscure benefit to choosing one approach over the other :)

Comment: It depends on the type of your variable. There is no strategy here, just necessity.

Comment: It's not really obscure, but when you use `split`, the Javascript interpreter is actually constructing a String and then calling `split` on it, rather than just constructing the array directly from your code.  It's more work for the implementation and less clear for the programmer, so I don't know why you would ever choose it. (Assuming we're dealing with literals; if you have data, then you process it however you receive it.)

Comment: please downvoters, state why.

Comment: it depends of the purpose, if i have a string to split, then i would use the string. if i have an array as data, then i would use the array.

Answer (score -1):

The only difference is readability (and for some people it might also be easier to type).

Some people consider `'one two'.split(' ')` more readable than the JavaScript notation of the array.

If you are used to JSON, however, you will consider the second one more readable as it is more clear what will happen. (And it’s a tick faster!)

Other languages even have this built right into the language. In Ruby for instance you could write `%w(one two)` producing an array with the strings "one" and "two".

Comment: There is no way that `"one two".split(" ")` is more readable than `["one", "two"]` which is more direct and shorter.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Is this an opinion or are you opposing my answer? (Research `%w()` for Ruby...)

Comment: Just an opinion on how that might not be the reason for why this is chosen over the array literal in the libraries OP mentioned, especially when libraries are often about performance.

Comment: %w() is readable in Ruby, but most Ruby code would not be readable if put in a Javascript program. Adding extra logic, including a string method that returns an array, around something that by itself resembles a readable pattern in another language, is not "more readable."

Comment: @djechlin I have no other explanation why someone would write code like this. (And I did not claim that a mix of Ruby or JS was readable, did I?)

Comment: Your answer doesn't distinguish why they did it from whether they should have. That's important.

Comment: @djechlin That’s another opinion, isn't it? `'one two'.split(' ')` might be slower and seems less readable to most of us but that does not make this code illegitimate. If the OP could provides an example of such a library we probably will find a clear answer. Like this, we can just guess.

Comment: Sure, it's my opinion that your answer conflates why they used the "split" form from whether they should have. It's also my opinion that that's important. It's my opinion that of the two opinions one may hold of which opinion is better, one opinion is *better* than the other, and it's also my opinion that this is a poor answer in the meantime.

Comment: @djechlin Please provide a better answer yourself if you know exactly how a good answer to this question should look like. My sentence about opinion was referring to the close reason of the question.

Comment: Question is closed, so I can't. FTR I voted to reopen.